# Not getting the figure number when calling a caption in overleaf

Tags: floats, overleaf

I'm using a poster template on Overleaf (Imperial College London template) but when I put in figures I'm not getting the figure number in the caption section.

This is my document preamble:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={table}]{beamer}
\usepackage[size=a0,orientation=portrait,scale=1]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile=singleslide,t]\centering
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]

\begin{column}{.47\textwidth}

\begin{figure}
     \centering
     \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=0.6\hsize]{Cauchy_arm1.PNG}
         \caption{$Q$ with two sign changes}
         \label{fig:Cauchy_arm1}
     \end{minipage}
\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.6\hsize]{Cauchy_arm2.PNG}
        \caption{$Q$ with one sign change}
        \label{fig:Cauchy_arm2}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}


\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Code output:
[image: out put of code]

I haven't used overleaf much and the times that I've used similar code in TeXmaker. It worked fine, I'm not sure why this isn't working here. Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: By default figures in a document created using the `beamer` class are not numbered. You could add `\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]` to the preamble of your document to get numbered figures.

Comment: @Rmano understood, ill update for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to use the subfigure functionality. An alternative way is as below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{}
    
\begin{figure}[ht!] 
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{a.png}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:my_label_a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{b.png}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:my_label_b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption here}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

which yields

[image]

Comment: Which documentclass did you use to compile your code? If I use `beamer`, just as the OP, I still get an unnumbered figure.

Comment: I updated above for ```beamer```. Please try above now.

Comment: thanks this works great :)

Comment: `graphicx` package is already loaded by `beamer`, so you not need to load it again.